# Default iterface/routes metric in Linux

Tags: linux, routing, route, network-interface, metric

When I run `ip route` on my Linux machine, I see

`default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eno1 metric 202`

I wonder, where this **202** metric is configured and what other `ip` commands use it.

Comment: Do you have the value 202 specified somewhere in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1`?

Comment: @Ramesh I don't have `/etc/sysconfig` (I'm using ArchLinux)

Comment: I don't know enough to provide a full answer but I'm pretty sure the metric default is selected by the kernel. The kernel is the piece of software that actually weights different routes anyways. `ip` is just a management tool for kernel configuration.

Comment: metric is generally not used, I have no metrics listed in my `ip route` output. It might be used if you're using a routing protocol via e.g. `zebra`, it indicates the (relative) cost of using that route. See e.g. [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779122(WS.10).aspx) for an explanation of metric. Where your value of 202 comes from can't be determined without more information.

Comment: @wurtel I find metrics useful for overriding routes created by a VPN client. As for the value, I suppose it's a default in ArchLinux.

Comment: @eugeney does it actually work? AFAIK the metric is not used in the kernel, only by routing software. For overriding routes you should use `ip rule` priorities, see [lartc FAQ](http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html) for details.

Comment: @wurtel Yes, it works fine. See [iproute2 cheat sheet](http://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/#Routes%20with%20different%20metric)